# proof of fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, extreme-value-theorem

hi i have problem understanding the proof of fundamental theorem of calculus.
this is part of general proof process using extreme value.

[image]

briefly this above saying that the derivate of integral is getting closed to f(x).
But
what i don't understand is that the **unit of result of integral is area**, so as h approaches 0, the integral result should be Zero ((f(x+h)-f(x))*0 = 0), not f(x) as in proof.

Hope somebody help me for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "unit" of the result? This is a theorem about Mathematics, using **abstract** real numbers, it's not about physical quantities.

Comment: Why do you write "f(x+h)-f(x))*0"?. Anyway, if you consider the integral as an area, and $f(x)$ and $h$ as lengths, there is no contradiction in what you have read.

Comment: The integral $\int_x^{x+h} f(t) \, dt$ indeed tends to $0$. It is the ratio of this integral and $h$ which tends to $f(x) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks for reply but could you give us more detail? The h infinitely approach to zero so I don’t understand how h tends to f

Comment: As $h\to 0$ the interval $[x, x+h] $ shrinks and the min and max values $m_h, M_h$ also come nearby $f(x) $ (due to continuity) and hence the ratio $\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt$ (which lies between $m_h$ and $M_h$) also comes near $f(x) $. The proof above misses out some key steps and rigor. It is much better to apply $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of continuity.

Comment: See a proof using $\epsilon, \delta$ at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2077638/72031